# Implementing an external merge sort

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to learn Python and am working on making an external merge sort using an input file with ints. I'm using heapq.merge, and my code almost works, but it seems to be sorting my lines as strings instead of ints. If I try to convert to ints, writelines won't accept the data. Can anyone help me find an alternative? Additionally, am I correct in thinking this will allow me to sort a file bigger than memory (given adequate disk space)

```
import itertools
from itertools import islice
import tempfile
import heapq

#converts heapq.merge to ints
#def merge(*temp_files):
#    return heapq.merge(*[itertools.imap(int, s) for s in temp_files])

with open("path\to\input", "r") as f:
    temp_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    temp_files = []
    elements = []
    while True:
        elements = list(islice(f, 1000))
        if not elements:
           break
        elements.sort(key=int)
        temp_files.append(elements)
        temp_file.writelines(elements)
        temp_file.flush()
        temp_file.seek(0)
        with open("path\to\output", "w") as output_file:
            output_file.writelines(heapq.merge(*temp_files))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense to me (`temp_files.append(elements)`? Merging inside the loop?), but here's a way to merge files sorting numerically:

```
import heapq
files = open('a.txt'), open('b.txt')
with open('merged.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(map('{}\n'.format,
                       heapq.merge(*(map(int, f)
                                     for f in files))))
```

First the `map(int, ...)` turns each file's lines into ints. Then those get merged with `heapq.merge`. Then `map('{}\n'.format` turns each of the integers back into a string, with newline. Then `writelines` writes those lines. In other words, you were already close, just had to convert the ints back to strings before writing them.

A different way to write it (might be clearer for some):

```
import heapq
files = open('a.txt'), open('b.txt')
with open('merged.txt', 'w') as out:
    int_streams = (map(int, f) for f in files)
    int_stream = heapq.merge(*int_streams)
    line_stream = map('{}\n'.format, int_stream)
    out.writelines(line_stream)
```

And in any case, do use `itertools.imap` if you're using Python 2 as otherwise it'll read the whole files into memory at once. In Python 3, you can just use the normal `map`.

And yes, if you do it right, this will allow you to sort gigantic files with very little memory.

Comment: Thank you, 

 out.writelines(map('{}\n'.format,
                       heapq.merge(*(map(int, f)
                                     for f in files))))

was the missing piece I was trying to find.

Answer (score 2):

Your elements are read by default as strings, you have to do something like:

```
elements = list(islice(f, 1000))
elements = [int(elem) for elem in elements]
```

so that they would be interpreted as integers instead.

That would also mean that you need to convert them back to strings when writing, e.g.:

```
temp_file.writelines([str(elem) for elem in elements])
```

Apart from that, you would need to convert your elements again to int for the final merging. In your case, you probably want to uncomment your `merge` method (and then convert the result back to strings again, same way as above).

Comment: does he need to str() typecast before doing writelines?

Comment: I've tried that, but writelines won't accept ints. Is there another method?

Comment: @user2361820 - the answer was edited, have you tried the edited one?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing **Kway** merge within the loop which will add a lots of **runtimeComplexity** . Better Store the file handles into a spearate list and perform a **Kway** merge

You also don't have to remove and add new line back ,just sort it based on number.

> sorted(temp_files,key=lambda no:int(no.strip()))

Rest of things are fine.

https://github.com/melvilgit/external-Merge-Sort/blob/master/README.md