# Sorting large text file in python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, external-sorting

Sort the content of a file based on second field, e.g.

Input file:

```
Jervie,12,M

Jaimy,11,F

Tony,23,M

Janey,11,F
```

Output file:

```
Jaimy,11,F

Janey,11,F

Jervie,12,M

Tony,23,M
```

We need to use external sort.
Input file can be of size 4GB. RAM is 1GB.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493806/implementing-an-external-merge-sort) but it does not work as it treats all the content as `int`. Also I have doubt related to the buffer size in each turn of the external sort. How to decide on that?

This sorts file with integers only.

```
file = open("i2.txt","r")
temp_files = []
e = []
while True:
    temp_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    e = list(islice(file,2))
    if not e:
        break
    e.sort(key=lambda line: int(line.split()[0]))
    temp_file.writelines(e)
    temp_files.append(temp_file)
    temp_file.flush()
    temp_file.seek(0)
file.close()

with open('o.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(imap('{}\n'.format, heapq.merge(*(imap(int, f) for f in temp_files))))
out.close()
```

I am able to create temporary files sorted on the second field, but how do I merge them based on that?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what have you tried? Try to write to a file as you read token by token.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the following code : 
Divide the big file into smaller files. Here it is assumed that max 4 lines can be read. So I initially divide the file into lines of 4 and sort them and write into temp files. Then read these files in pairs 2 lines from each file and merge them. Corner cases are not handled but, this should be a starter for others to think.

```
f = open("i1.txt", "r")
temp_files = []
e = []
while True:
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    e = list(islice(f, 4))
    if not e:
        temp_file.close()
        break
    # e.sort(key=lambda line:int(line.split()[1]))
    e.sort(key=lambda line: int(line.split()[1]))
    temp_file.writelines(e)
    temp_files.append(temp_file)
    temp_file.flush()
    temp_file.seek(0)
f.close()

aux = []
z = 0
while len(temp_files) != 1:
    while z < len(temp_files)-1:
        tem = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        t1 = temp_files[z]
        t2 = temp_files[z+1]
        t1.seek(0)
        t2.seek(0)
        n = 2
        e1 = None
        e2 = None
        while True:
            if not e1:
                e1 = list(islice(t1, 2))
            if not e2:
                e2 = list(islice(t2, 2))
            if not e1 and not e2:
                break
            elif e1 and not e2:
                tem.writelines(imap('{}'.format,e1))
                e1 = None
                continue
            elif not e1 and e2:
                tem.writelines(imap('{}'.format,e2))
                e2 = None
                continue
            i = 0
            j = 0
            while i<len(e1) and j<len(e2):
                l1 = e1[i]
                l2 = e2[j]
                if int(l1.split()[1]) == int(l2.split()[1]):
                    tem.writelines(imap('{}'.format,[l1,l2]))
                    i+=1
                    j+=1
                elif int(l1.split()[1]) < int(l2.split()[1]):
                    tem.writelines(imap('{}'.format,[l1]))
                    i+=1
                else:
                    tem.writelines(imap('{}'.format,[l2]))
                    j+=1
            if i>=len(e1):
                e1 = None
            else:
                e1 = e1[i:]
            if j>= len(e2):
                e2 = None
            else:
                e2 = e2[j:]
        z+=2
        aux.append(tem)
        t1.close()
        t2.close()
        tem.flush()
        tem.seek(0)
    temp_files = aux
    z = 0
    aux = []
with open("o.txt",'w') as out:
    out.writelines(imap('{}'.format,temp_files[0]))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using out of the core processing with Blaze (http://blaze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ooc.html)