# Merging files on disk in Python

Tags: python, merge, file-handling

I am trying to merge key-value pairs stored in multiple files. The files themselves are large so I want to do this in memory. The files are sorted, and contain 1 key-value pair per line, so normal k-way merge would work but I don't know how to iterate through the files together. Also in case I encounter multiple data points with the same keys, I want to combine them (add their values together) so the simple solution in [Implementing an external merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493806/implementing-an-external-merge-sort) does not work.I have tried using readlines to iterate over the files and storing indices, but readlines loads the entire file into memory so it does not acheive my need. As clarified by comments, the question boils down to reading consecutive lines from multiple files without using a `for line in file` loop.

Comment: _readlines loads the entire file into memory so it does not acheive my need_ So read one line at a time.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the code you're struggling with [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JohnGordon The problem being the way I know to iterate over IOstream is using a for loop, but I can't do that one at a time for multiple files like i need to for k-way merge

Comment: You can call `file.readline()` to read a single line.  Is that the part you're missing?

Comment: you can have N files open at the time, put them in a list, and you can read a byte or line from any file you have open, be sure to close all the files you have opened

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes that is exactly what i needed! Thank you! If you could put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your real question was "how do I arbitrarily read the next line from a file, without using a `for line in file` loop?"

The answer to that is `file.readline()`.

Comment: Or just `next(file)` which I would argue is more idiomatic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or just use `heapq.merge` instead of trying to reimplement it, then they wouldn't even have this issue.